# How to identify a object is changed?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, model, nsobject

I want to know that is there any way to identify the changes in any object. Lets take a object of any class. As any object has some memory space and if we change object's any property, then some change should occur in this memory space. So is there any way to identify this change.

I have a class and it has a lot of properties and I want to know that is there any property changed or not instead of comparing every property's previous and current value.

Please clarify me if I am getting something wrong and suggest me for solution.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: You should look up documentation on KVO. The core API is nasty to use, but you can create some nice wrappers very easily.

Answer (score 2):

What about key-value observing? 
U can add a listener to your property like this:

```
YourClass *object = [YourClass new];
[object addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"property" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];
```

then, when smith changes a method

```
 -(void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary     *)change context:(void *)context
{

}
```

will be fired automatically. So, u don't need to compare changes manually, but, nevertheless u will need to add observers to properties, you are interested in

Comment: Thanks Alex for your answer. I will update you after applying this.

Answer (score 1):

Just looking at memory consumption would not be enough - storing the number 1 or the number 2 takes exactly the same amount of space ...

I would either go the **KVO route** (see alex's answer) or implement a kind of **dirty flag** which you set whenever a property of the object is changed (in the `-(void)setXXX:(type)value {}` method). Of course you would have to compare the new value with the current one before setting the new value, or if you want to know whether an object is changed compared to a starting state you even would have to store the starting value in addition to each value property.

To make it more general you can also implement the all properties in a dictionary, but then you loose type checking and nice accessor methods ...

Answer (score -1):

Set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug.

Do that and post the backtrace.

Usually, this means that you corrupted memory, but it may also mean that you have an over-released object. Try Build and Analyze, too.